# Connect / Tether iPhone to Windows-based Visual Studio 2017

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, visual-studio

I have iPhone connected to Windows 10 directly. I'd like to send / debug using phone instead of an iOS simulator. Is this possible?

Comment: Wih Framework do you want to use?

Comment: Using HTML5, css, & JavaScript and running it through PhoneGap Build. I've been downloading .ipa and installing via iTunes, but was wondering if an easier way exist via VS2017.